# mat-expansion-panel [expanded] input does not work properly when set asynchronously

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-expansion-panel

I have a mat-accordion which has a mat-expansion-panel set like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of menuItems; index as i" [hideToggle]="item.hideToggle" [expanded]="item.active">
```

You can see the "expanded" input is true if "item" has the boolean property "active" evaluating as true. Well, here is the weird part: if "item.active" is set synchronously, for example on the ngOnInit method of my component, everything works and the panel opens. However, if "item.active" is set asynchronously, e.g. inside a "subscribe" method of an observable, panel does not open. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as this where I was loading the contents of the expansion panel asynchronously. The issue is caused by `ngFor` directive re-rendering the DOM when the contents change via the default `trackByFunction` implementation that returns the object as the identity.[see here](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction).

I got around this by providing my custom trackBy function

```
identify(index:number, item:any){
    return item.ExternalId;   // this is the unique id 
}
```

then invoking it in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items;trackBy:identify">
```